# Using `pipe`, `dup2` to duplicate an `exec`ing childs STDOUT - output only shows up when child exits

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, exec

I've read all the answers for this question on this site and they're all wrong (i.e. flat out does not work, or doesn't do what I want it to).

I have a tracer program, that wants to be able to control the output of the tracee, (possibly by formatting the output from the traced program, so that it can finally write that data to some stream, mixed with it's own output, and since I can format the data since I know where it comes from, it's all good). In other words, I want to be able to pre-process the output of the child, before I, for example dump that output to the parent's stdout (or some other pipe, file or connection/socket). The problem is the data only ever shows up if the child *dies*.

Doing the following, clearly does not work:

```cpp
#define READING_END 0
#define WRITING_END 1

int pipes[2];
if (-1 == pipe(pipes)) {
  PANIC("Failed to set up communication pipes\n");
}

  auto pid = fork();
  switch (pid) {
  case 0: {

    close(pipes[READING_END]));
    dup2(pipes[WRITING_END], STDOUT_FILENO));
    dup2(pipes[WRITING_END], STDERR_FILENO));
    // some ptrace stuff:
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    execv(some_application, some_app_args);
  } break;
  default: {
    close(pipes[WRITING_END]);
    // for simplicity's sake of the code, I'll just put it in an endless read loop here:
    std::thread read_input{[&]()
      char buf[10];
      auto read_data = 0;
      // this only ever outputs anything when the exec'ed application exits
      while ((read_data = read(pipes[READING_END], &buf, 10)) != 0 && read_data != -1) {
        //fmtlib library, think of Python. Anyway, this code never runs anyhow
        fmt::println("READ {}", buf);
      }
      fmt::println("READ DATA {}", read_data);
    }};
    for (;;) {
      // doing tracer logic here
      // yet we NEVER see any of the output from the fork-then-execed application.
    }
    break;
  }
```

And I think I have a suspicion as to why - all (literally *all*) the examples provided on StackOverflow give examples that *only* work when the child's exited. Being the tracer, obviously that is of absolutely no use to me.

So the question is, how do I redirect this output in a "stream-like" fashion, i.e. without having to wait for the child to exit to actually see anything on the pipe?

Any answers to this, would be massively appreciated.

Edit:
The problem is not flushing. Even if the `exec`ing application explicitly flushes it's `STDOUT` fd, it's as though *still* a minimum amount of writes have to occur before it actually gets flushed. Some 100's of lines of 50'ish bytes, which seem to be closely related to the `PIPE_BUF` of 512 bytes.

Would writing a pseudo terminal alleviate this problem? Making the `pipe` somehow look like a terminal?

Comment: You write to buffered streams, but never flush the output.  You shouldn't be surprised that nothing is delivered until the process terminates.

Comment: The problem isn't the flushing. If the execing code flushes (via for instance fsync), it still doesn't show up. It's as though there exists a _minimum_ buffer limit that has to be reached for anything is even flushed, even though pipes explicitly are defined to not have this behavior.

Comment: If a newly execed processes' standard output is a pipe or file it'll typically be block buffered internally (language/runtime depending, of course, but in the case of C and C++ on unixy systems, at least). If the program doesn't flush stdout on occasion you won't see its output until enough data is written or the process exits. Using a pty makes it line buffered so you see the output sooner.

Comment: You might have [`stdbuf(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stdbuf.1.html) available to avoid having to manually set up ptys. Or have the execed program call `fflush(stdout)` on occasion if you have control over its code (not `fsync()`, which is kernel level and useless here)

Comment: What is your *tracer logic*? How did you release the process after `raise(SIGSTOP);`? I fixed syntax errors in your example, removed `ptrace()` and `rise()`, compiled it and run. I can see output of child process immediately as soon as it printed.

Comment: @SimonFarre Flushing *is* the issue; `fsync` does not flush the output buffer.  It ensures that anything that has been flushed will be on the backing medium, but it doesn't actually flush the stream.  If you write `fprintf(ofp, "foo"); fsync(fileno(ofp));`, the string `foo` is not necessarily in the file.  If you want to flush the data and sync it, you would need to do `fprintf(ofp, "foo"); fflush(ofp); fsync(fileno(ofp));`.

Comment: @dimich The tracer logic is simple in the example, it continues any task/task leader (meaning, it's a simple continue all) in this particular case. The tracer logic wasn't the issue. The issue was two fold, as Shawn pointed out, block buffering - but even when I wrote the tracee application to flush, it would not show up, it would only show up on exit or above 512 bytes. A PTY is what I need though, as I need the tracee to think it's running like a normal application with a terminal on the other side (otherwise debugging terminal applications will go bad). Regardless, I need line buffering.

Comment: @WilliamPursell - seeing as how I have resolved the issue with a PTY which also fulfills the other specifications in my original question - I tried using streams on the tracee side and with fflush it didn't show up. I must have done something wrong or incorrectly flushed.

That's irrelevant though, I need line buffering and I need the stdio of the tracee to think it's connected to a terminal, without polluting the tracer application.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I decided to answer my question, for posterity. For a tracer application, that needs the tracee application to behave as though it's connected to a terminal, *without* polluting the tracer application, the below answer is the correct one. The problem involved mainly block buffering, though I had little success with writing a test tracee that did manual flushing either.

You need to create a pseudo terminal like I asked in my question; because even though the exec'ed child flushes, it will not show up, until reaching some (unknown to me) threshold, even though it seems to me that pipe's in linux are not supposed to work this way, i.e. if the user has flushed, that data should be available - which wasn't the case, and was what led me to ask this question.

The Linux Programming Interface book has examples on how to write a pseudo terminal interface, but here's a quick example - one that entirely lacks error checking and only means to guide any user who reads this and it's written in C++:

```cpp
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <variant>

// type that contains name of the pseudo pty (path) and the fd for it
struct MasterPty {
  std::string name;
  int fd;
};

// Our own "pty fork" result, returned to the parent, the child only gets a pid_t = 0

struct PtyParentResult
{
  MasterPty master_pty;
  pid_t pid;
};

// Open the master pty
MasterPty
open_pty_master() noexcept
{
  const auto master_fd = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
  grantpt(master_fd);
  unlockpt(master_fd);
  std::string pty_name = ptsname(master_fd);
  return MasterPty{.name = pty_name, .fd = master_fd};
}

// wrap the fork system call and setup the pseudo terminal 
std::variant<pid_t, PtyParentResult>
pty_fork(const termios *slave_termios, const winsize *slave_winsize)
{
  auto master_pty = open_pty_master();

  auto child_pid = fork();

  // like a normal fork, parent returns here
  if (child_pid != 0) {
    return PtyParentResult{.master_pty = master_pty, .pid = child_pid };
  }

  // child fall through
  setsid();
  auto slave_fd = open(master_pty.name.c_str(), O_RDWR);

#if defined(TIOCSCTTY)
  ioctl(slave_fd, TIOCSCTTY, 0);
#endif
  if (slave_termios != nullptr)
    tcsetattr(slave_fd, TCSANOW, slave_termios);

  if (slave_winsize != nullptr)
    ioctl(slave_fd, TIOCSWINSZ, slave_winsize);

  // Take control of STDIO on the child
  dup2(slave_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
  dup2(slave_fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(slave_fd, STDERR_FILENO);

  if (slave_fd > STDERR_FILENO) {
    close(slave_fd);
  }
  // child return
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  termios original_tty;
  winsize ws;
  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &original_tty);
  ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &ws);

  auto fork_result = pty_fork(&original_tty, &ws);

  switch (fork_result.index()) {
  case 0: { // if the variant's type index == 0, means we're a child
    // do your fork-child exec'ing here
    execv(application_cmd_path, app_args);
    break;
  }
  default: { // typeindex == 1, let's pull out the result from std::variant
    const auto result = std::get<PtyParentResult>(fork_result);
    // here's my same thread example, endlessly polling the master pty fd. Now we get the data we want when it's flushed. 
    // And since we're operating like a pseudo-terminal, we will also be *line-buffered* which is what a tracee program being debugged would expect.
    std::thread read_input{[&]() {
      char buf[25];
      auto read_data = 0;
      fd_set inFds;
      for (;;) {
        FD_ZERO(&inFds);
        FD_SET(result.fd, &inFds);
        if (FD_ISSET(result.fd, &inFds)) {
          auto num_read = read(result.fd, buf, 25);
          if (num_read > 0) {
            fmt::println("{}", buf);
            std::memset(buf, 0, 25);
          }
        }
      }
    }};
    for (;;) {
      // main application loop
    }
    break;
  }

}
```

Much thanks goes to the fantastic author of "The Linux Programming Interface" Michael Kerrisk, a book which I obviously should've known contained the know-how on how to solve it.

Comment: All that does is to reduce the stdio buffering.  It's a very heavyweight approach compared with adding a call to `fflush(stdout)` or `std::cout << std::flush`.

Comment: Flushing *doesn't* work for above example. There still is an unseen threshold that has to be hit first. 2nd of all I wrote that I have a *tracer* program, it may or may not know the internals of the tracee.